# Perl Convert Long IPv6 Address To Compact Notation

Tags: perl, ipv6

I have a long IPv6 address in a scalar like

```
2001:0db8:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

and would like to get the compact notation:

```
2001:db8::.
```

Does the main Perl package `/usr/lib/perl5/...` contain a module that will do this?

Does the Net::IP module?

If not, does someone have a few lines that would do this?

Sort of the opposite of what [Net::IP::ip_expand_address](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm#ip_expand_address) does.

Comment: There is no mention of the compact notation in Net::IP besides the function you've already found. We cannot tell you what's included in your Perl because we don't know which version of Perl (and on what OS, because certain vendors include different things) you have. You can check your Perl version by running `perl -v`. You can check if a certain module is in code with the `corelist` utility. You can check if a module is available with `perl -MModule::Name=99`, which will either complain about the module missing, or tell you that your version is too low.

Comment: @simbabque That `=99` trick only works if the module uses `Exporter`, which does a version check on any import argument that looks like a number. For a general solution you need `'-MModule::Name 99'` (with a space). And even that fails for modules (like `File::Slurp`) that have a version number greater than 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Net::IP indeed offers the [ip_compress_address](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm#ip_compress_address) method to compress an IP.

Answer (score 2):

The `NetAddr::IP` module offers the `short` method to do just that.

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use NetAddr::IP;

my $ip = NetAddr::IP->new( '2001:0db8:0:0:0:0:0:0' );

print "Long version: " . $ip->addr . "\n";
print "Short/Compact version: " . $ip->short . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The module [IPv6::Address](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPv6::Address) can do that when you call its `addr_string` method, but it's not in core. However, you can borrow [the code that does it](https://metacpan.org/source/ADUITSIS/IPv6-Address-0.207/lib/IPv6/Address.pm#L298) fairly quickly.

All I did was take the part that creates the compact notation, and wrap it in a `sub`.

```
sub compact {

    # taken from IPv6::Address on CPAN
    my $str = shift;
    return '::' if($str eq '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0');
    for(my $i=7;$i>1;$i--) {
            my $zerostr = join(':',split('','0'x$i));
            ###print "DEBUG: $str $zerostr \n";
            if($str =~ /:$zerostr$/) {
                    $str =~ s/:$zerostr$/::/;
                    return $str;
            }
            elsif ($str =~ /:$zerostr:/) {
                    $str =~ s/:$zerostr:/::/;
                    return $str;
            }
            elsif ($str =~ /^$zerostr:/) {
                    $str =~ s/^$zerostr:/::/;
                    return $str;
            }
    }
    return $str;
}


print compact('2001:0db8:0:0:0:0:0:0');
```

This will print

```
2001:0db8::
```

It seems to be ok with already compacted strings too.